# Python module importation error

Tags: python, package, openstack, openstack-neutron

Trying to install Openstack Kilo, nova logs returns

```
TRACE nova from neutronclient.neutron import v2_0 as neutronv20
TRACE nova ImportError: No module named neutron
```

I tried to import some modules of `neutronclient` with Python :

```
>>> from neutronclient.neutron import v2_0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named neutron

>>>  from neutronclient import common

>>>
```

`neutronclient.common` is loaded.  But like `neutronclient.common`, `neutronclient.neutron` has a folder (and *__init__.py*) in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/neutronclient/`

Why this python package is not detected? I tried to reinstall the package with `apt-get` but it's not better.

Comment: Try using `pip install neutron` instead of `apt-get`. Hope it could help

Comment: I solved errors making `pip uninstall python-neutronclient`  ,  then `pip install neutronclient`  and finally  `pip install python-neutronclient --upgrade`  .   Strangely, the folder `neutron` has not changed...       But now, it works, thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command.
apt-get install python-neutronclient

or 
pip install neutronclient

or download the tar file from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-neutronclient